# Wordpress/JavaScript troubles

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I want to use a sliding gallery that I wrote. I've been trying to enqueue it and I'm not having any luck getting it to work. When I look at the developer tools to see what sources are being pulled/if the console is throwing any errors, I'm not even seeing the JavaScript file show up.

file structure as shown on google dev tools for front-page.php (where the slider will exist)
[image: Screenshot of the file structure in the Google Developer tools Source tab]

file structure as shown on google dev tools for all other pages
[image]

functions.php code:

```
function glv_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'glv-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'glv_scripts' );
```

Comment: your folders are named wrong and incomplete. The `themes/glv` folder should be two folders for example with `glv` as subfolder of `themes`. I would reupload everything first.

Comment: Your theme is missing the `js` folder and the script for your slider.  Based on your image your theme only has a stylesheet.

Comment: @Cray that is a VS code thing since the theme folder only has one sub folder or theme it displays them like `themes/theme-folder`... if there was another theme folder it would display in the traditional tree format.

Comment: @mikerojas The screenshot was taken on the front-page.php file, which is ultimately where the slider will exist. The js folder is there but I only see it if I'm on any of the other pages. I'll put another picture in the main post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized I was missing the footer call in front-page.php, so it wasn't showing up because I had it set to true for the footer but forgot the footer. :S